# How to restart specific named cached in AppFabric

Tags: caching, powershell, windows-server-2008, appfabric

I have installed AppFabric on server and I want multiple instances to point to the cache. So I created named cache for each instance and pointed app to these caches.

Now I want to clear cache of a specific named cache. But I didn't found any command secific for this. All Microsoft provides is 'Restart-CacheCluster'. I cant use this option as this will clear all named cache.

Is there any way i can restart/clear specific named cache??

**After using ClearRegion**

On using ClearRegion method, it is not clearing all the stats, it just clears the item count. So will it harm anyway?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691538/asp-net-appfabric-cache-missing-flush-clear-and-count-getcount-methods/4691798#4691798) for a method of creating a `Flush` method for a cache.

Comment: I tried this but its not clearing all the stats.
Attached screenshot for same