# CacheItem regionName property responsibility/uses?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, .net-4.0

The MSDN documentation doesn't explain in detail what its used for.

Since its optional, I almost assume its like metadata of some sort.

How I look at it right now, I'd like to use it as a way to specify caches for specific users only such as:

```
new CacheItem(key: "keyName", value: objectData, regionName: "userName")
```

What is the responsibility of the regionName property of the CacheItem class?  What is it used for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Caching Application Data by Using Multiple Cache Objects in an ASP.NET Application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/03/22/caching-application-data-by-using-multiple-cache-objects-in-an-asp-net-application.aspx) <sup>*([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20100701090254/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/03/22/caching-application-data-by-using-multiple-cache-objects-in-an-asp-net-application.aspx))*</sup>

> The custom class demonstrates how you would store the cached data in a
> named region in memory. **The built-in memory cache object does not
> support the concept of regions** but it is used in this blog to
> demonstrate how you would implement regions in a custom cache class.
> A cache region is a partition in memory that is reserved for storing
> one or more cache objects. A cache region helps organize cache objects
> in memory.

(my emphasis)

Answer (score 0):

The `RegionName` parameter in all the `MemoryCache` methods [existed to support](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching/ObjectCache.cs,63) Microsoft's AppFabric (formerly known as  [Velocity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2010/june/msdn-magazine-windows-azure-cache-real-world-usage-and-integration#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20Windows%20Server%20AppFabric%2C%20formerly%20codenamed%20%E2%80%9CVelocity%2C%E2%80%9D)) caching API.

The AppFabric API [was discontinued in 2017](https://www.scaleoutsoftware.com/technology/appfabric-caching-what-now/), and Microsoft [suggested moving to Redis.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150405234501/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2015/04/02/windows-server-appfabric-1-1-ends-support-4-2-2016.aspx)

So now the parameters exist as baggage, like a tombstone.

### Bonus Reading

- [AppFabric get named cache object count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226321/appfabric-get-named-cache-object-count)
- MSDN: [DataCache.GetObjectsInRegion Method (String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/ff424917(v=azure.100))